# Increase dynamic VDI disk size

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm running Linux (OpenSuse) host (Oracle VirtualBox) with Win 7 guest.  I configured the VM with a VDI format disk that grows dynamically as required.  Windows currently has 3.5 Gb free but I need to increase that to 9Gb in order to install SP1 and I'm not sure how to go about it.

I found this http://derekmolloy.ie/resize-a-virtualbox-disk/ which is Windows Host/Linux Guest so it gives me a good heads up but anything more specifically applicable to my configuration would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

turns out this is very easy:

- in linux host terminal VBoxManager modifyhd --resize {Megabytes} {fileName}
- In Windows Guest: open Disk Management Applet and use resize partition function